# だが attached to the subject/topic

Tags: copula, conjunctions

`だが` is often attached to the subject/topic of a sentence as follows, with my supposed translation.

> 近くに住む叔父だが, 最近具合が悪いと聞いている.
>   'Speaking of my uncle who lives close-by, I've heard lately he's isn't doing fine.'

Does such `だが` give the subject a special meaning? Is the translation correct?

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically, it is the copula `だ` with conjunct `が`, probably used in a cleft sentence with some omission. `が` often connects contrasting clauses, but as with this case, it can just connect two clauses that do not contrast. The literal translation is

> '**On top of the fact that** (it) **is** my uncle who lives close-by (that I am going to talk about), I've heard that he isn't doing fine lately.

A more natural translation may be close to yours:

> 'Speaking of my uncle who lives close-by, I've heard that he isn't doing fine lately.

The mistake you made is the scope of `最近` 'lately'. It should not be "heard lately" but should be "not doing fine lately". Or, maybe you took that correctly, but your translation is ambiguous.

Comment: You probably unintentionally dropped the “who lives close-by” part from the translations.

Comment: Just to add, the same usage exists for other conjuncts similar to が: 来月フランスに行くけど、お土産には何がほしい? does not really contrast two clauses, but the first part just sets up the context.